# How to change user.dir ( or current directory in command prompt ) in java?

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt

When I go to a directory and make a jar file in command prompt, it works correctly. But, when I am in dir1 and make a jar file from dir2, it makes the jar file in dir1 and the jar file has error :

> couldn't find main class.

I thought it works if I change current directory by java code.
If it works from command prompt, it will be correct in java code.

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop>jar cfe Main.jar Main F:\Java\Files\Main.class



C:\Users\username\Desktop>java -jar F:\Java\Files\Main.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Comment: can you show us the log where it works?

Comment: what is the problem with changing to the right directory? Had a look at the -C parameter? like `jar cfe F:\Java\Files\Main.jar Main -C F:\Java\Files  Main.class`

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying that the `Main.jar` be generated in the current directory. Include the full path of the jar file when you are generating it:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop>jar cfe F:\Java\Files\Main.jar Main F:\Java\Files\Main.class
```

Comment: thanks, folder is now correct, but still there is Error couldn't found...